# How to delete the partial values of column in R

Tags: r

I have a data "movesdata" and column as Start_time such as:

```
Group   Start_time                      End_time
walking 2016-10-10T12:02:54+02:00   2016-10-10T12:06:18+02:00
walking 2016-10-10T12:06:19+02:00   2016-10-10T12:16:47+02:00
walking 2016-10-10T12:16:55+02:00   2016-10-10T12:17:14+02:00
```

I want to separate the values of columns Start_time and End_time "2016-10-10T12:02:54+02:00" to just time 12:02:54. I want other values to be removed, but I can not figure it out how? The problem is date changes after 3-4 rows but addition of GMT (+02:00) is constant. I don't want both the date (2016-10-10T) and GMT (+02:00) can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this: the first way is to actually use date conversions:

```
> d <- strptime ("2016-10-10T12:02:54+02:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+02:00")
> d
[1] "2016-10-10 12:02:54 EDT"
> format (d, "%H:%M:%S")
[1] "12:02:54"
```

I've cheated a little here at the end, since `strptime` has a time zone offset like `+0200` rather than `+02:00`, and I'm assuming that the offset stays the same.

The second way is to use `grep`, which you really should learn, but it's pretty complex in this case:

```
> gsub ("^.+T([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})\\+.+$",  "\\1", "2016-10-10T12:02:54+02:00")
[1] "12:02:54"
```

(`grep` is actually a little hard to use for this (common) use case in R, so I used `gsub` instead. In this use case it's much easier.)

I'd recommend the first option in this case, since it will give you errors for malformed dates, while the second option will gladly accept a time like `25:37:99`. You may think that the incoming times are all correct, but it's always good to exercise defensive programming. Certainly if you need to reformat a date/time it's better to use the date/time functions.

Remember that you can do this as a vectorized operation:

```
movesdata$startTime <- format (strptime (movesdata$Start_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+02:00"), "%H:%M:%S")
```

I just did it with a single string to illustrate. (I named the destination column differently so you could compare the two. I try to keep original columns around until I know manipulations are working as I expect.)

Comment: Thank you, Wayne. I cannot be enough grateful. I worked with gsub but the problem is now once I have changed the the data values using gsub as gsub ("^.+T([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})\\+.+$",  "\\1", movesdata$Start_time). now when I look for whole dataset (head(movesdata)) the columns values are not changed as in the previous step.

Comment: Did you assign the changed values back into the dataset? `gsub`, like most R functions, doesn't change the data in-place if you didn't assign the result back into the array -- as I did in the last code section, above, no change will be made.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Load packages and make dummy dataframe (time/dates in character format)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df_char <- data_frame(Group = rep('walking', 3),
                      Start_time = c('2016-10-10T12:02:54+02:00', 
                                     '2016-10-10T12:06:19+02:00', 
                                     '2016-10-10T12:16:55+02:00'),
                      End_time = c('2016-10-10T12:06:18+02:00',
                                   '2016-10-10T12:16:47+02:00',
                                   '2016-10-10T12:17:14+02:00'))
```

Check dataframe

```
glimpse(df_char)
    Observations: 3
    Variables: 3
    $ Group      <chr> "walking", "walking", "walking"
    $ Start_time <chr> "2016-10-10T12:02:54+02:00", "2016-10-10T12:06:19+02:00", "2016-1...
    $ End_time   <chr> "2016-10-10T12:06:18+02:00", "2016-10-10T12:16:47+02:00", "2016-1...
```

Clean data, keeping date and timezone information in case you need it later

```
df_char_clean <- df_char %>%
     # Separate Start_time into date and time
     separate(col = Start_time, 
              into = c('Start_date', 'Start_time'),
              sep = '[T]') %>%
     # Remove '+02:00' timezone
     mutate(Start_time = str_extract(string = Start_time,
                                     pattern = '.+(?=[+])')) %>%
     # Separate End_time into Date, time, timezone
     separate(col = End_time, 
              into = c('End_date', 'End_time'),
              sep = '[T]') %>%
     separate(col = End_time,
              into = c('End_time', 'tz'),
              sep = '[+]')

# If you only want times
# select(df_char_clean, 
#        Group, 
#        Start_time, 
#        End_time)
```

Re-check dataframe

```
glimpse(df_char_clean)
    Observations: 3
    Variables: 6
    $ Group      <chr> "walking", "walking", "walking"
    $ Start_date <chr> "2016-10-10", "2016-10-10", "2016-10-10"
    $ Start_time <chr> "12:02:54", "12:06:19", "12:16:55"
    $ End_date   <chr> "2016-10-10", "2016-10-10", "2016-10-10"
    $ End_time   <chr> "12:06:18", "12:16:47", "12:17:14"
    $ tz         <chr> "02:00", "02:00", "02:00"
```